# JsonObjectRequest timeout error, but StringRequest works fine

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an android application that requests a JSON object to a REST Service (ASP.NET MVC). I'm using Volley to do this.

The code for doing this:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest (
    Request.Method.GET,
    "http://192.168.1.253:8090/MyController/MyAction?myParameter=5B1C084B-EFE1-4292-BAF4-A2C30126171D",
    null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK!" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Response code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "My App", "Searching");
```

When I debug, the error is a `TimeoutError` instance.

Now, when I switch from `JsonObjectRequest` to `StringRequest`, the request works fine, and returns the JSON string, as expected.

The json that the service is returning is:

```
[{"Id":"0f376a18-f311-4bc3-b236-a2c3012bbbe1","Name":"HiAll","Route":[{"Order":0,"Latitude":24.207535461007971,"Longitude":65.26852548122406,"Stop":false,"Flag":true},{"Order":1,"Latitude":24.208240008486147,"Longitude":65.26927649974823,"Stop":true,"Flag":true},{"Order":2,"Latitude":24.209531668746457,"Longitude":65.270671248435974,"Stop":false,"Flag":true}]}]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: that url does not look very restful...

Comment: your listener should be a `Listener<JSONObject>`, not a `Listener<String>`

Comment: the difference between String and JSON requests object in Volley is the content-type `"application/json; charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: @njzk2 I've corrected the code. It was my mistake when I've posted.